# Render React components which require styles on server

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have React.js components that require styles inside:

```
import './styles.css
import React from 'react';

export default class Basket extends React.Component {
    ...
}
```

Now I want to make my app isomorphic and prerender it on server..

There's no surprise that Babel starts to complain about `css` files:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/dmitri/github/app/src/client/pages/styles.css: Unexpected token (3:5)
  2 |
> 3 | body {
    |      ^
  4 |     background-color: #ddd;
  5 | }
  6 |
```

How to make it work? There's similar discussion on `node-jsx` - https://github.com/petehunt/node-jsx/issues/29

Should I add `if (browser)` statements for this imports?

Comment: using systemjs serverside might work: https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs

Comment: What if you preprocessed imports containing `.css` out of the source? [recast](https://github.com/benjamn/recast) can do this. Later on it is probably possible to implement a Babel plugin for the same task. At the moment there's no stable API so I cannot recommend that yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a different approach, but check out [Radium](http://projects.formidablelabs.com/radium/). You can declare your styles as JS objects, so the server won't have to know or care about what css is.

Example from the Radium page:

```js
var React = require('react');
var Radium = require('radium');
var color = require('color');

var Button = React.createClass(Radium.wrap({
  displayName: "Button",

  propTypes: {
    kind: React.PropTypes.oneOf(['primary', 'warning']).isRequired
  },

  render: function () {
    // Radium extends the style attribute to accept an array. It will merge
    // the styles in order. We use this feature here to apply the primary
    // or warning styles depending on the value of the `kind` prop. Since its
    // all just JavaScript, you can use whatever logic you want to decide which
    // styles are applied (props, state, context, etc).
    return (
      <button
        style={[
          styles.base,
          styles[this.props.kind]
        ]}>
        {this.props.children}
      </button>
    );
  }
}));

// You can create your style objects dynamically or share them for
// every instance of the component.
var styles = {
  base: {
    padding: '1.5em 2em',
    border: 0,
    borderRadius: 4,
    color: '#fff',
    cursor: 'pointer',
    fontSize: 16,
    fontWeight: 700,

    // Adding interactive state couldn't be easier! Add a special key to your
    // style object (:hover, :focus, :active, or @media) with the additional rules.
    ':hover': {
      background: color('#0074d9').lighten(0.2).hexString()
    },

    // If you specify more than one, later ones will override earlier ones.
    ':focus': {
      boxShadow: '0 0 0 3px #eee, 0 0 0 6px #0074D9',
      outline: 'none'
    },
  },

  primary: {
    background: '#0074D9'
  },

  warning: {
    background: '#FF4136'
  }
};
```

Remember, if you're not a fan of inline css, you could always define your styles in a separate JS and import them.

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same needs as you. I use **webpack** for package my app. In webpack, you can define severals variables like this:

```
var define = new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    "process.env": {
        BROWSER: JSON.stringify(true)
    }
});
```

In my jsx file:

```
if (process.env.BROWSER) {
    require('my-css');
}
```

I think, there are other way to manage css. This is one way to do.